# Why is req.isAuthenticated() false even though strategy passes

Tags: express, passport.js

I have the following simple LocalStrategy...

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done){
        console.log(`Checking the user and password`);
        if(username === "user" && password === "password"){
            console.log("Correct!");
            return done(null, true);
        }
        return done(null, false);
    }
));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(`User is ${user}`);
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(`Deserialize User is ${user}`);
    done(null, user);
});
```

Then I have the following middleware....

```
const checkAuth = (req, res, next) =>{
    console.log(`Passport is ${JSON.stringify(req.session.passport)}`);
    console.log(`Is Auth ${req.isAuthenticated()}`);
    if(req.path === '/login' || req.isAuthenticated()){
        console.log("Authenticated");
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
};
...
this.express.use(checkAuth);
```

When I run this and login with `user` `password` I get the following...

```
Passport is undefined
Is Auth false
Authenticated
```

This is the POST to login so it is considered authenticated regardless so this looks right, however, after that we see the password is checked and it is correct but the session still does not define the passport object so it redirects back to login...

```
Checking the user and password
Correct!
Passport is undefined
Is Auth false
...
```

The session does not seem to have anything saved to is after the return...

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
```

Here is how I set the session...

```
    this.express.use(session({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true
    }));
    this.express.use(passport.initialize());
    this.express.use(passport.session());
```

Why is authenticated false and how do I set it correctly?